# Install GDBserver in OSX

Tags: macos, gdb, gdbserver

I can use `brew` to install GBD or download and compile GDB from source but either way GDBserver does not get installed. How can I get GDBserver running in OSX?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell this is not currently possible. I built the gdb project version 8.0.1 from source on macos (High Sierra) and gdbserver was not built.

The gdbserver-related output from ./configure ended with this line:
"Error: target not supported by gdbserver."

version 8.0.1 of gdb works fine on my macos*, just not gdbserver.

(*) after codesigning the binary and running this:

```
$ echo "set startup-with-shell off” >> ~/.gdbinit
```